# String interpolation with html form text

Tags: javascript

I'd like to insert variables to an snippet of html text like

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <textarea class="form-control" name="comment" id="editComment25"></textarea > 
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="commentBtnID25">Save Edits</button >
    <a href="#">cancel</a>
</form >
```

I tried with an clumsy solution:

```
var comment_id = $(e.target).attr("id")
var editCommentID = "editComment" + comment_id
var commentBtnID = "commentBtnID" + comment_id
var commentEditForm = '<form action = "#" method = "post"><textarea class="form-control" name ="comment" '
commentEditForm += 'id="' + editCommentID + '"></textarea > <br>';
commentEditForm += '<button class="btn btn-primary" id="' + commentBtnID + '">Save Edits</button > <a href="#">cancel</a></form >'
```

Is interpolation possible here as it does in python?

```
commentEditForm = """"
    <form action="#" method="post">
        <textarea class="form-control" name="comment" id="%s"></textarea > 
            <br>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="%s">Save Edits</button >
            <a href="#">cancel</a>
    </form >
    """ %(editCommentID, commentBtnID)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would probably be easier to use a template literal to define the desired string all at once:

```js
var comment_id = '25'; // $(e.target).attr("id")
var commentEditForm = `
<form action="#" method="post">
    <textarea class="form-control" name="comment" id="editComment${comment_id}"></textarea > 
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="commentBtnID${comment_id}">Save Edits</button >
    <a href="#">cancel</a>
</form >
`;
console.log(commentEditForm);
```